# Which Conan book involves his son Conn being seduced by a woman?

Tags: story-identification, conan

Which Conan the Barbarian book involves his son Conn being seduced by a girl?

> The girl is a monster of some kind who uses illusions to trick people... He is saved by seeing the monster reflected in his cuirass (breastplate) armour.

There might be another aspect of the story that involves a priest or a druid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is in **Conan of Aquilonia** by L. Sprague de Camp and Lin Carter. The scene you remember is in the final story "Shadows in the Skull", where young Conn is seduced away from a banquet by a serpent woman. He sees her reflection after she changes into a serpent, just before she tries to kill him.

The druid is Deviatrix, a white druid out of Pictland, who uses the Heart of Ahriman, last seen in the REH classic tale "The Hour of the Dragon", to break Thoth Amon's Black Ring in Stygia.

Comment: Thank you! That's the one!